# Assign value to a variable from list object converted from JSON in Flutter

Tags: json, list, flutter

I'm really new to flutter. I tried searching for this question and although I have found a solution but not all my problems are solved, as most of it just use return.

I have a JSON that i get from API calling here:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "message": "LOGIN_SUCCESS",
    "user": {
        "id": 1219,
        "email": "john@example.com"
        "name": "John Doe",
        "category": 1,
        "branch": 1004,
        "lastlogin": "2020-12-04 03:12:43"
    }
}
```

I already create the class for user as below

```
class User {
  int id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String category;
  String branch;
  String lastLogin;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.category,
    this.branch,
    this.lastLogin
  });

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> datauser){
    return User(
        id: datauser['id'],
        name: datauser['name'],
        email: datauser['email'],
        category: datauser['category'],
        branch: datauser['branch'],
        lastLogin: datauser['lastlogin']
    );
  }

}
```

and a result class as below..

```
class Result {

  String message;
  User user;

  Result({
    this.message,
    this.user
  });

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> resultData){
    return Result(
        message: resultData['message'],
        user: User.fromJson(resultData['user'])
    );
  }

}
```

now here comes my problem as i don't know how to move forward from this point

```
login() async {
    List<User> users;
    final response = await http.post("myUrlWithAPIcalls",
        body: {"email": email, "password": password});
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var rest = data['user'] as List;
    users = rest.map<User>((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

so the question is, how can i assign the value i get from the JSON that has converted into list into a variable?

now in example if it was only a simple JSON object, i could do it like this..

```
final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    int id = data['id'];
    String name = data['name'];
    String email = data['email'];
    String category = data['category'];
    String branch = data['branch'];
```

but how can i do that in a list object?

as of anyone was wondering why do i do like this, i was trying to save the data into a sharedpref class that i copied from someone else code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared preferences are not meant to store objects. Use something like [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) to persist objects (official cookbook [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite)).

I don't understand why your JSON shows one user's data, but the `login()` function seems to decode a list of users.

I'm guessing that's what you want :

```
login() async {
    final response = await http.post("myUrlWithAPIcalls",
        body: {"email": email, "password": password});
    final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    var user = User.fromJson(data['user']); // the variable you want
}
```

You don't say where that `login()` function is, or what you want to do with that `User` object. FYI, an essential part of Flutter is [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro).

Comment: I'm using shared preferences because I only want to keep the data temporarily. in native android, I used to use shared preference for this because the sqlite would keep the data in the device. I will look into sqflite for the moment. My JSON only decode 1 user data as for returning who is trying to logging in and using the app for the moment. As for your answer, how can i manipulate the value 1 by 1 from the user? eg. the email, name and etc.

Comment: Well, the values are in the user object, e.g `user.name`, `user.branch` etc. Shared prefs are as persistent as sqflite, they will only disappear when you uninstall. If you want to keep the data only while the app is open, use a state management solution as I said.

Comment: yes. that works! I'll learn more about state management. thanks for your help.